# Android Soft Keyboard - Key preview popup is blocked/cut off at the top edge of the keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, popup, key, preview

I'm working on a keyboard and am now focused on the key previews. I'm using a drawable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="10sp" android:right="10sp" android:bottom="5sp" android:left="10sp" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="0sp" android:right="0sp" android:bottom="1sp" android:left="0sp" />
        <solid android:color="#d4d4d4" />
        <corners android:radius="4sp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="0sp" android:right="0sp" android:bottom="1sp" android:left="0sp" />
        <solid android:color="#dddddd" />
        <corners android:radius="4sp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="#FFD1D6D9" />
        <corners android:radius="4sp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and have tried setting,

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

on the keyboard XML file. I am looking for a similar behavior to GBoard's popups, where the drawable pops up over every element. The bottom row works perfectly fine; the middle row pushes the popup down a bit (looks like it always sets the top edge of the key preview popup to the top of the keyboard if it exceeds it), and the top row really doesn't show anything at all. Have I forgotten a setting or will Android just not let me do this properly? How do you think Google did it in GBoard?

Comment: Have you got any solutions for the problem?